# Trying to fit a fixed width container into a full-width (100%) parent?

Tags: html, css

so I'm new to coding and am attempting to create a website with some full-width (100%) containers that include fix-width containers inside...I've tried playing with figures and divs alike, but neither was working.

This is an image of the site mockup: [image]

Here is the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<header>

    <div class="header">

    .logo
    .searchbar
    .phone numbers insert

    </div> <!--closes header div-->

</header>
<div class="navband">
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Engineered Integrated Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Employment</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</div> <!--closes navband div-->
<div class="content">

    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>Content Here</p>

</div> <!--closes content div-->
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 175px;
    background-color: #ff8400;
}

#nav {
margin-top: 280px;
width: 100%;
}

.nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #08172d;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav a:hover{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    color: #ff8400;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The above code displays the fixed width layout (while the entire body behind it remains white), but I don't know how to include individual full-width parent divs for the header, nav bar, and content area without ignoring the wrapper (fix-width) completely, which is what was happening when I used a figure method...any ideas?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/ --guide I was using for the 'figure class' trick. (although it didn't fix my problem, unfortunately) :(

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to make individual full-width div classes for the header, nav, and content areas (displayed in a grey background color) and instead of a fixed-width (wrapper), manually position the individual elements into place? (company logo, search bar...) while centering a 'content div' with text-align left for the Header and subsequent content further down the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `max-width` property

> The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of an element.
>   This prevents the value of the width property from becoming larger than max-width.
>   **Note**: The value of the `max-width` property overrides width.

become

```
.parent{
  width: 100%;
}
.child{
  padding: 25px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 540px;
}
```